# ReactJS tutorial code ported ES6 Code not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#declaring-a-winner) has a tutorial on building a tic tac toe game with React. There's this function that checks to see if a winning move is made.

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

it works but the for loop could be improved to use `for x in lines` like so

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let line in lines) {
    const [a, b, c] = line;
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

but when I tried that it didn't **find** a winning so I resorted to the older code.

I'm not sure why though the second edit failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]];
    for (let line in lines) {
        console.log(line);
        const [a, b, c] = line;
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Run this code. Your `line` variable is index of array, not inner array (e.g. [0, 1, 2]).

EDIT:

As kristaps mentioned in comment proper solution is `let line of lines` (**of** instead of **in**).

Comment: Your code still says `let line in lines`, did you mean `let line of lines`?

Comment: I just pointed out why the code did not work properly. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

here in your first code you are using for loop which can excess 2d array in proper way
example below program will produce out put like

```
    [
      0,
      1,
      2
    ]
```

```js
const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    console.log(lines[i]);
    }
```

and also for each loop is use for excess each element at a time for example below program will produce output like

```
    1
    2
    3
```

as it

```js
const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let line in lines) {
    const [a, b, c] = line;
    console.log(line)
    }
```

i think you can understand what happened here

Comment: yes and to return the content not the index it should be `for (let line of lines)`

Comment: yah that a point **for each** loop is use for each element at a time